# All queries are so slow on mysql NDB cluster

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster

Here is my situation:

I got over 10G of web logs (around 30 million rows) and I mainly search it with various conditions.

e.g.:

```
select * from tbl 
where ip = '123.123.12.3' 
  and agent = 'mozillar' 
  and body like '%script%'
```

As data is getting bigger, a simple query takes minutes, so I am trying to create some distributed database with MySQL cluster.

I have built 1 management server, 1 SQL (api) server and 4 data nodes on a Google cloud VM. They have 2 CPUs and 8 GB per each instance.

**PROBLEM:**

When I try to restore data from an .sql file, each insert statement takes almost 2~3 seconds!

3 sec * 30m row = FOREVER!

The select query also disappointed me, it takes almost 100 times longer than normal InnoDB.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there any better solution for my purpose?

config.ini

```
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2    
DataMemory=5G    
IndexMemory=128M   
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=1000000
MaxNoOfLocalOperations=1100000
MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=327680
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=256
FragmentLogFileSize=32M
SharedGlobalMemory=512M
DiskPageBufferMemory=512M
DiskIoThreadPool=8

[ndb_mgmd]
NodeId=1
hostname=10.142.0.7
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/mgmt


[ndbd]
NodeId=11
hostname=10.142.0.8
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/data1
[ndbd]
NodeId=12
hostname=10.142.0.9
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/data2
[ndbd]
NodeId=13
hostname=10.142.0.10
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/data3
[ndbd]
NodeId=14
hostname=10.142.0.11
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/data4

[mysqld]
NodeId=100
```

All the nodes are connected to management server as expected

```
-- NDB Cluster -- Management Client --
ndb_mgm> show
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     4 node(s)
id=11   @10.142.0.8  (mysql-5.6.29 ndb-7.4.11, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=12   @10.142.0.9  (mysql-5.6.29 ndb-7.4.11, Nodegroup: 0)
id=13   @10.142.0.10  (mysql-5.6.29 ndb-7.4.11, Nodegroup: 1)
id=14   @10.142.0.11  (mysql-5.6.29 ndb-7.4.11, Nodegroup: 1)
[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @10.142.0.7  (mysql-5.6.29 ndb-7.4.11)
[mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
id=100  @10.142.0.2  (mysql-5.6.29 ndb-7.4.11)
```

---

Additional info:

```
    Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rule_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `detection_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `uri` text,
  `site` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `detection_string` text,
  `detection_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `action` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no`),
  KEY `no` (`no`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21682043 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redundant index.** A `PRIMARY KEY` is an index, so there is not need for the redundant `KEY no(no)`.  (`DROPping` this will speed up things a little.)

**Agent.** Where's the `agent` in the schema?  Is it a varchar?  or enum?  or normalized `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.  The last would save space, hence improve speed, but would complicate the insert.

**Better index.** Replace `INDEX(ip)` with `INDEX(ip, agent)`.  This will speed up the given `SELECT` some.  (But I suspect the agent is usually the same for a given ip.)

**Country code** There are very standard 2-letter country codes; use them instead of the bulky `varchar(50)`.

**Batching.** For now for the real speedup...  Batch the inserts.  Collect them in a table, swap tables, `INSERT..SELECT`, etc.  [Details here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).  That technique is self-adjusting; so if things get slower, they actions also get more efficient.  That link also explains how to efficiently normalize.

**Tuning.** `IndexMemory=128M` seems unreasonably small.

**Back to InnoDB?**

> The select query also disappointed me, it takes almost 100 times longer than normal InnoDB.

The techniques I have mentioned are well tuned for InnoDB; I have less experience with NDB Cluster.  Maybe you should go back to InnoDB and we can work on making that better?  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of RAM.

**IPv6.** A side note:  IPv4 needs only `VARCHAR(15)`; IPv6 needs `(39)`.  And ip addresses may as well be `CHARACTER SET ascii`, not utf8.  (No significant performance benefit here.)